# KieScanner and Spark com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors

Tags: maven, apache-spark, guice, drools, kie

I am getting this Guice Provision error when using KieScanner with my Drools + Spark program. I am using Spark 1.6.2 with Drools and Kie-cl 6.4.0 and I am reading my drool rules from my local maven repository. The spark application runs and works when I ks.newKieScanner( kieContainer ); is removed, so there seems to be an issue when implementing it.

Code initializing KieScanner:

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId("DroolsDynamic.group", "DroolsDynamic.artifact", "1.0-SNAPSHOT");
    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer( releaseId );
    KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
    KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kieContainer );
```

Guice Provision Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: **com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:**

    1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem was bound.
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

    1 error
          role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      roleHint: 
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:69)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:53)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:49)
        at org.kie.scanner.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:136)
        at org.kie.scanner.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:99)
        at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.setKieContainer(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:89)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieScanner(KieServicesImpl.java:139)
        at com.sample.SnortTest.main(SnortTest.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

    1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem was bound.
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

    1 error
          role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      roleHint: 
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:102)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:75)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:66)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

    1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem was bound.
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

    1 error
          role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      roleHint: 
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:119)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:90)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

    1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem was bound.
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]]
      while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

    1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        ... 24 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>DroolsDynamic.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>DroolsDynamic.artifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>



        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
            <!-- Additional configuration. -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>kinesis-asl</id>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
              <artifactId>spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
    </project>
```

I've been stuck on this for awhile changing up the pom.xml and whatnot, and I'm still stuck. Any help or idea why this is happening will help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, or one just like it. To solve it I added the following shade plugin's "transformers" section:

```
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer"/>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"/>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer" >
        <resource>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</resource>
    </transformer>
</transformers>
```

I believe I found this answer somewhere else online, but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue and, in my case, it was resolved by adding the following dependency into my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess that other implementations other than aether can be used as well.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, there was no change when I added the dependency. I'm getting the exact same error.